# Codeigniter min_length[] not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I have this code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('quadra_numero', 'Quadra número', 'required|trim|numeric|xss_clean|min_length[3]|max_length[3]|callback_valida_quadra_setor');
```

The `max_length[3]` works but not the `min_length[3]`.

I've checked the returned value with `strlen($quadra_numero)` and it returns me 2 characters but the validation seems to ignore it.

In my form I have the number 091, in my database it is a VARCHAR to keep the 0 that is 
necessary.

If I post 0912 it will return the error for max_length but if I change it to 91 will pass the validation.

If I post 09 it will work, only with the 0(zero) is removed it won't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help.

--EDIT
I have tried to use exact_length[8] and got the same results. The problem is with the 0(zero).

Comment: Another user from CI Forum told me "I didn’t check for min and max length for bug but there is a rule exact_length you could use." but it didn't work =/ I guess I'll have to check for number length and add a 0(zero) if length is equal 2....still waiting for help

Comment: What's in the callback? Have you tried using *only* the min/max rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just at a first glance, you probably need to typecast the variable to a string before sending it in.

```
$quadra_numero = (string)$quadra_numero;
```

or

```
$quadra_numero = strval($quadra_numero);
```

and see if that takes care of the problem. The strlen is converting the variable to a string before it checks the length, but the validation probably isn't